# How can we add onblur event for lightning:inputField

Tags: lightning-events, lightning-recordeditform, lightning-inputfield

I need to add onblur event for lightning:inputField. Right now as per the documentation (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:inputField) I dont see a direct by which I can do that.

```
<aura:component>
    <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="recordEditForm"
                           objectApiName="Contact">
        <lightning:messages />
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name" />
        <lightning:button class="slds-m-top_small" type="submit" label="Create new" />
    </lightning:recordEditForm>
</aura:component>
```

Can anybody suggest a way to do this by any custom method?

Comment: What about keyup?

Comment: Because blur I guess we can't as we don't have any control on `lightning:inputField` component.